# Textbox builder UI pattern similar to listbuilder UI pattern

Tags: angular

I am looking to build a free form text box builder almost similar to the listbuilder as shown in the image attached. 
I need to enter values in the textbox on the front end html and on click of the Add button the value should be moved to the textarea on the right. And the user should be able to add multiple input values and keep adding them to the textarea. Same like the listbox shown in the image. but i want to do it with textbox. Any suggestions? I am using Angular2 Typescript and html to do this.

[See Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Szx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you implement that same logic if you had two arrays to represent the two lists?

Because, that's the Angular equivalent - implement your logic for moving items between two arrays, and then just use Angular for your visual representation of those arrays (i.e. create two `<select>` elements that use ngFor to iterate over those two arrays to build your list of `<options>`)